# LabelBinarizer behaves inconsistently because of NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to transform columns with text of a DataFrame to a one hot encoded matrix. This worked fine for some moment but has stopped working for reasons unknown to me. The message says: "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'"  To me this seems nonsense as I use only tekst data. When I repeat the experiment with a small dataset the LabelBinarizer works just fine and produces the desired output.

I noticed that the X_train dataframe has a size of 4.6 GB. My machine has just 8 GB. Is there some memory limit I should be aware of? All numerics are rather small, should I convert to int32 and float32?

I am able to reproduce the error below. But I am not sure whether this provides sufficient information.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

lb=LabelBinarizer()

s=['a','b','c','b','a']

df=pd.DataFrame (s)

df = pd.Series (s)

dd = X_train['state']

type(dd)
Out[9]: pandas.core.series.Series

type(df)
Out[10]: pandas.core.series.Series

lb.fit(dd)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-5ec245111e31>", line 1, in <module>
    lb.fit(dd)

  File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 296, in fit
    self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y)

  File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 275, in type_of_target
    if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):

  File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 214, in unique
    ar.sort()

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'


lb.fit(df)
Out[12]: LabelBinarizer(neg_label=0, pos_label=1, sparse_output=False)

df.value_counts()
Out[13]: 
a    2
b    2
c    1
dtype: int64

dd.value_counts()
Out[14]: 
MI    228601
CA      5020
TX      2420
FL      2237
IL      1310
SC      1304
OH       967
NY       673
MN       632
GA       535
NV       484
UT       477
PA       466
NJ       395
VA       385
NC       353
MD       349
AZ       329
ME       261
OK       248
AL       215
TN       207
WA       192
MA       182
IA       159
WI       159
OR       153
MO       151
CO       147
KY       146
IN       106
AR        82
LA        81
AK        79
UK        77
NB        77
MS        64
CT        60
DC        58
ON        51
DE        50
KS        37
RI        35
SD        33
ID        33
MT        28
NM        21
BC        17
WY        12
HI        10
NH         9
VT         7
VI         6
WV         6
PR         5
QC         5
QL         3
ND         2
BL         2
Name: state, dtype: int64

len(df)
Out[15]: 5

len(dd)
Out[16]: 250306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps its input data may contain missing values.

```python
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lb = LabelBinarizer()

s = ['a','b','c','b','a', np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=["state"])

df_binarized = lb.fit_transform(df['state'])
df_binarized

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kuroyanagi/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-45-f16e01b4e1be>", line 4, in <module>
    df_binarized = lb.fit_transform(df['state'])
  File "/home/kuroyanagi/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 494, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/home/kuroyanagi/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 296, in fit
    self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y)
  File "/home/kuroyanagi/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 275, in type_of_target
    if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
  File "/home/kuroyanagi/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 210, in unique
    return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
  File "/home/kuroyanagi/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 277, in _unique1d
ar.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

If there is no missing value, it works as follows.

```python
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = ['a','b','c','b','a']
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=["state"])

df_binarized = lb.fit_transform(df['state'])
df_binarized

Out[46]:
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Yes! That was the culprit. Thanks a lot. I scanned my column to test each value's type and noticed some NaN's which were interpreted as float's. Very confusing. When you ask for the dtype of a pandas Series it might be lying to you. I changed the title to reflect this finding.

Comment: Thank you for changing the title. I have also encountered the same problem in the past. Probably useful for those who have the same problem.

Comment: I am very glad you shared this solution. If only the error message had been more clear it wouldn't have cost me a day.